# OpenCV 2.4.7.2 + windows 8.1 + Visual Studio 2013 == Error

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, linker, visual-studio-2013

I've installed new Windows 8.1 system with the following:

OpenCV 2.4.7.2
   Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

I'm tying to work with my OpenCV projects but get's the following error:

```
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Users\yirmio\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\OPENCV_PROJECT\x64\Debug\OPENCV_PROJECT.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Dev\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_core247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Dev\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_features2d247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Dev\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_highgui247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'E:\Dev\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin\opencv_nonfree247d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr120d.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[4752] OPENCV_PROJECT.exe' has exited with code -1073741515 (0xc0000135) 'A dependent dll was not found'.
```

I've searched Google for houres with no solution to this problem...
Allready changed the libraries and all project settings...

Hope for some help...

Thanks!
Yirmi.

Comment: if you got an older project, that was built with 245, you'll probably need to change all the library names to 247

Comment: Please try to work with VS 2010 or 2012.. 2013 has some issues with OpenCV..

Comment: Thank you both, i've updated the topic...  @scap3y i'm realy going to unistall 2013 because of this, i'm just giving it last chance...

Comment: Please read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2013/06/28/c-11-14-stl-features-fixes-and-breaking-changes-in-vs-2013.aspx)..

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever tried [this](http://karanjthakkar.wordpress.com/2012/11/21/usin-opencv-2-4-2-with-visual-studio-2012-on-windows-7-64-bit/)?

1. setting PATH
2. add compiler 'vc11' and linker to visual studio